# How to make Angular 7 scroll to component repeated with ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I have a looping template I need to scroll to specific item when that item get's active how do i do that.

My template loop is :

```html
<div class="tabs-list-item-container"> <!-- this is a horizontal scrollable wrapper -->
   <app-tab-list-item *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [tabSession]="tab" [class.active]="tab.isActive"></app-tab-list-item>
</div>
```

The tab object has isActive property which I need to use and scroll to that component can it be achieved?

Comment: See the example https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/virtual-scrolling-in-angular-7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the user selects an item, the below method should get invoked. `scrollIntoView()` will scroll to the element which has `.active` class

```
scrollToActive() {
   document.querySelector('.active').scrollIntoView();
}
```

Comment: that worked in a way, but its a vanilla js, anyway i would upvote that